# error_callback in multiprocessing.Pool apply_async in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Function `apply_async` of `multiprocessing.Pool` class has argument `error_callback` in *Python 3*. But this argument is missing in *Python 2*.

Is there any trick to achieve the same functionality in Python 2 ? Ideally I would like to write code which runs in both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried python3 yet. But for me, to catch the errors in the child process, I put the function that runs in child process within a

```
import traceback


try:
    your code that can make error
except Exception as e:
    print e
    return False, traceback.format_exc()
else:
    return True, result
```

So that I will know if something goes wrong.

EDIT: I change the return format as OP's comment so that the child process returns a tuple `(is_success, result or error traceback message )`

So that main process will first read the flag `is_success` and then handles the second argument accordingly.

Comment: Well, but I need to inform the main process that the exception was raised in the child process. I also need to know which exception was raised and get the full traceback. This is something that multiprocessing in Python 3 naturally has. Some things seem so incredibly complicated in Python 2...:(

Comment: @V.K. `e` contains the exception's message and `traceback` gives you full traceback. Main process will know if an exception was raised in the child by the return value. You can either return `None` or `e` or `traceback.format_exc()` to tell the main process that error was raised.

Comment: Thank you... it is trivial in fact. Your solution almost does what I need. I wrap my function in a try/catch block and its output is packed as tuple (success, result). If exception is raised, then success = False, result=exception_raised and if it is not raised, then success = True, result=value_returned. Then the tuple is passed to main process with the normal callback of apply_async. In the main process, it is unpacked and checked. I tested it and it works. If you just could rewrite your solution to this form, I will accept it. And you are right, traceback is a part of the exception.

Answer (score -1):

### TL;DR

Instead of adding extra arguments to return, use the [successful()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.successful) method that [AnycResult objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) provide you. That's what it's there for.

### Explanation

Calls to `apply_async` return an AsyncResult object. These objects have a method called `successful()` that will tell you if the target process exited via an exception. Calling `successful()` will return true or false depending on whether the subprocess exited with an exception. Here is an example:

```
import multiprocessing

def good_func(arg):
    arg += 1
    return arg

def bad_func(arg):
    arg += 1
    raise Exception # force an exception to be raised
    return arg

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

good_result = pool.apply_async(good_func, (1,))
bad_result = pool.apply_async(bad_func, (1,))

pool.close()
pool.join()

print(good_result.successful()) # prints True
print(bad_result.successful())  # prints False
```

This code returns:

> True
>   False

You can then add a conditional expression that calls your cleanup or error handling code if the call to `successfull()` returns false.

Furthermore, if you need the traceback, you can wrap the body of your subprocess function in a try/except block and return a string version of the traceback in the event of an exception. It could look something like this version of `bad_func`:

```
import sys
import traceback
import multiprocessing

def good_func(arg):
    arg += 1
    return arg

def bad_func(arg):
    try:
        arg += 1
        raise Exception
        return a
    except Exception as error:
        # capture the exception and bundle the traceback
        # in a string, then raise new exception with the string traceback
        raise Exception("".join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())))

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

good_result = pool.apply_async(good_func, (1,))
bad_result = pool.apply_async(bad_func, (1,))

pool.close()
pool.join()

print(good_result.successful()) # prints True
print(good_result.get())        # prints good result
print(bad_result.successful())  # prints False
print(bad_result.get())         # prints traceback
```

This code produces this output:

> True
>   2
>   False
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "async_err.py", line 29, in 
>       print(bad_result.get())
>     File "/user/peteoss/encap/Python-2.7.6/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing  /pool.py", line 554, in get
>       raise self._value
>   Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "async_err.py", line 13, in bad_func
>       raise Exception
>   Exception

You should note a few things:

1. You will get two tracebacks: one from the failed called to `get()`, and the second one is the traceback that you bundled into a string in your subprocess.
2. If you wrap the subprocess function in a try/except block, you will need to reraise an exception when you handle it, otherwise `get()` will return false.
3. The `AsyncResult.successful()` and `AsyncResult.get()` methods are available in all versions of CPython that have the multiprocessing library, so this method meets your requirement of writing version-agnostic code.