# Python Multiprocessing Locks

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This multiprocessing code works as expected. It creates 4 Python processes, and uses them to print the numbers 0 through 39, with a delay after each print.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def job(num):
  print num
  time.sleep(1)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)

lst = range(40)
for i in lst:
  pool.apply_async(job, [i])

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

However, when I try to use a multiprocessing.Lock to prevent multiple processes from printing to standard out, the program just exits immediately without any output.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def job(lock, num):
  lock.acquire()
  print num
  lock.release()
  time.sleep(1)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
l = multiprocessing.Lock()

lst = range(40)
for i in lst:
  pool.apply_async(job, [l, i])

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Why does the introduction of a multiprocessing.Lock make this code not work?

Update: It works when the lock is declared globally (where I did a few non-definitive tests to check that the lock works), as opposed to the code above which passes the lock as an argument (Python's multiprocessing documentation shows locks being passed as arguments). The code below has a lock declared globally, as opposed to passing as an argument in the code above.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

l = multiprocessing.Lock()

def job(num):
  l.acquire()
  print num
  l.release()
  time.sleep(1)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)

lst = range(40)
for i in lst:
  pool.apply_async(job, [i])

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: >  It works when the lock is declared globally 

The lock also has to be instantiated before the pool. Otherwise, the worker processes will fork before the lock is created and would not be able to share it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you change `pool.apply_async` to `pool.apply`, you get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 15, in <module>
    pool.apply(job, [l, i])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 244, in apply
    return self.apply_async(func, args, kwds).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
RuntimeError: Lock objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

`pool.apply_async` is just hiding it. I hate to say this, but using a global variable is probably the simplest way for your example. Let's just hope the [velociraptors](http://xkcd.com/292/) don't get you.

Comment: Thanks! Using apply as opposed to apply_async seems like a useful way to debug these issues.

Comment: Yeah, it seems a bit silly that `apply_async` doesn't even print a warning message.

Comment: Agree, but as workaround it is possible to use in Python 3 error_callback of apply_async. Workaround for Python 2 -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986885/error-callback-in-multiprocessing-pool-apply-async-in-python-2

Answer (score 18):

Other answers already provide the answer that the `apply_async` silently fails unless an appropriate `error_callback` argument is provided. I still found OP's other point valid -- the official docs do indeed show `multiprocessing.Lock` being passed around as a function argument. In fact, the sub-section titled "Explicitly pass resources to child processes" in [Programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming) recommends passing a `multiprocessing.Lock` object as function argument instead of a global variable. And, I have been writing a lot of code in which I pass a `multiprocessing.Lock` as an argument to the child process and it all works as expected.

So, what gives?

I first investigated whether `multiprocessing.Lock` is pickle-able or not. In Python 3, MacOS+CPython, trying to pickle `multiprocessing.Lock` produces the familiar `RuntimeError` encountered by others.

```
>>> pickle.dumps(multiprocessing.Lock())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-66dfe1355652> in <module>
----> 1 pickle.dumps(multiprocessing.Lock())

/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/synchronize.py in __getstate__(self)
     99
    100     def __getstate__(self):
--> 101         context.assert_spawning(self)
    102         sl = self._semlock
    103         if sys.platform == 'win32':

/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py in assert_spawning(obj)
    354         raise RuntimeError(
    355             '%s objects should only be shared between processes'
--> 356             ' through inheritance' % type(obj).__name__
    357             )

RuntimeError: Lock objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

To me, this confirms that `multiprocessing.Lock` is indeed not pickle-able.

**Aside begins**

But, the *same* lock still needs to be shared across two or more python processes which will have their own, potentially different address spaces (such as when we use "spawn" or "forkserver" as start methods). `multiprocessing` must be doing something special to send Lock across processes. This [other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45040019/4383754) seems to indicate that in Unix systems, `multiprocessing.Lock` may be implemented via named semaphores that are supported by the OS itself (outside python). Two or more python processes can then link to the *same* lock that effectively resides in one location outside both python processes. There may be a shared memory implementation as well.

**Aside ends**

*Can we pass `multiprocessing.Lock` object as an argument or not?*

After a few more experiments and more reading, it appears that the difference is between `multiprocessing.Pool` and `multiprocessing.Process`.

`multiprocessing.Process` lets you pass `multiprocessing.Lock` as an argument but `multiprocessing.Pool` doesn't. Here is an example that works:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock


def task(n: int, lock):
    with lock:
        print(f'n={n}')
    time.sleep(0.25)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('forkserver')
    lock = Lock()
    processes = [Process(target=task, args=(i, lock)) for i in range(20)]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

Note the use of `__name__ == '__main__'` is essential as mentioned in the "Safe importing of main module" sub-section of [Programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming).

`multiprocessing.Pool` seems to use `queue.SimpleQueue` which puts each task in a queue and that's where pickling happens. Most likely, `multiprocessing.Process` is not using pickling (or doing a special version of pickling).

Answer (score 10):

I think the reason is that the multiprocessing pool uses `pickle` to transfer objects between the processes. However, a `Lock` cannot be pickled:

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> import pickle
>>> lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
>>> lp = pickle.dumps(lock)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    lp = pickle.dumps(lock)
...
RuntimeError: Lock objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
>>>
```

See the "Picklability" and "Better to inherit than pickle/unpickle" sections of https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#all-platforms

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25558333/7360722), [`Manager.Lock()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.Lock) might be appropriate here. It can be passed to the Pool, because it can be pickled.

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

def job(lock, num):
  lock.acquire()
  print num
  lock.release()
  time.sleep(1)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
m = multiprocessing.Manager()
l = m.Lock()

lst = range(40)
for i in lst:
  pool.apply_async(job, [l, i])

pool.close()
pool.join()
```