# Cant stop\kill all processes at once produced by multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I need to stop\kill all processes when there is any error\exception. I found on StackOwerflow solution to kill all processes using `psutil`, but  from time to time I have an issue - when `psutil` kills child and main processes, new processes may start and code continues to execute.

```
import psutil

class MyClass:
    parent_pid = 0
    ids_list = range(300)

    def main(self):
        self.parent_pid = os.getpid()
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)

        for osm_id in self.ids_list:
            pool.apply_async(self.handle_country_or_region,  
                             kwds=dict(country_id=osm_id),
                             error_callback=self.kill_proc_tree)

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    def kill_proc_tree(self, including_parent=True):
        parent = psutil.Process(self.parent_pid)
        children = parent.children(recursive=True)

        for child in children:
            child.kill()
        psutil.wait_procs(children, timeout=5)

        if including_parent:
            parent.kill()
            parent.wait(5)

    def handle_country_or_region(self, country_id=None, queue=None):
        pass
        # here I do some task
```

It seems that I need to terminate pool rather than kill processes, but in this case, if I do

```
pool.close()
pool.terminate()
pool.join()
```

my terminal stops doing anything, new line is fully empty (i.e without ">>>") and nothing happens.

Ideally I want to have the next flow: If there is any error\exception, stop\kill all code executions and back to interactive prompt in terminal.

Can anyone help me to make it work properly?
I use Python 3.5 and Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite simple - put 'killer'-function inside the 'main'.

Full code looks like:

```
class MyClass:
    ids_list = range(300)

    def main(self):
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)

        def kill_pool(err_msg):
            print(err_msg)
            pool.terminate()

        for osm_id in self.ids_list:
            pool.apply_async(self.handle_country_or_region,     
                             kwds=dict(country_id=osm_id),
                             error_callback=kill_pool)

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    def handle_country_or_region(self, country_id=None, queue=None):
        pass  # here I do some task
```

If anyone needs to use `queue`, below is extended variant of the code, which shows how to finish `queue` in a correct way, that avoids having zombie processes:

```
import pickle
import os
import multiprocessing

class MyClass:
    ids_list = range(300)
    folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'app_geo')
    STOP_TOKEN = 'stop queue'

    def main(self):

        # >>> Queue part shared between processes <<<
        manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        remove_id_queue = manager.Queue()

        remove_id_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.remove_id_from_file,
                                                    args=(remove_id_queue,))
        remove_id_process.start()
        # >>> End of queue part <<<

        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)

        def kill_pool(err_msg):
            print(err_msg)
            pool.terminate()

        for osm_id in self.ids_list:
            pool.apply_async(self.handle_country_or_region,     
                             kwds=dict(country_id=osm_id),
                             error_callback=kill_pool)

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        # >>> Anti-zombie processes queue part <<<
        remove_id_queue.put(self.STOP_TOKEN)
        remove_id_process.join()
        manager.shutdown()
        # >>> End

    def handle_country_or_region(self, country_id=None, queue=None):
        # here I do some task
        queue.put(country_id)

    def remove_id_from_file(self, some_queue):
        while True:
            osm_id = some_queue.get()
            if osm_id == self.STOP_TOKEN:
                return
            self.ids_list.remove(osm_id)
            with open(self.folder + '/ids_list.pickle', 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump(self.ids_list, f)
```

Comment: too bad i can't do this in python 2 :(

Comment: @Adi, sorry, I did not work with python 2, so can not help. Just checked, in `Python 2.7.12` there is `multiprocessing` with all methods I used - https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: If I remember correctly, according to the doc `error_callback` is made in order to make life easier. So how about to make your own `error_callback` as shown here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986885/error-callback-in-multiprocessing-pool-apply-async-in-python-2 ? Based on my code, you can do like `pool.apply_async(self.handle_country_or_region, kwds=dict(country_id=osm_id, your_error_callback=kill_pool))` and `def handle_country_or_region(self, country_id=None, queue=None, your_error_callback=None)`. In `try-except` just call `your_error_callback()` in case of error. Seems should work

Comment: I prefer using an Event() object as flag for shutdown (exit the infinite loop), in your approach you are putting only 1 "poisonous pill" in the queue won't that just be taken by (only) the first available process leaving the others still alive ?

Comment: @LohmarASHAR, I cant be sure now, because it was long time ago, but as I remember all processes were terminated, that is exactly what I needed. I will read about Event(), thanks.