# Not able to pass shared value object (Multiprocessing.Value('i',10)) in pool apply_async arguments

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory, multiprocess

Passing shared value object to apply_async argument dosent run the object(probably dosent recognize)

```
from Multiprocessing import Value,Pool,apply_async
val = Value('i',1)

pool = Pool(processes=2)

pool.apply_async(some_func1_accepts_argument,args=(val,))
pool.apply_async(some_func2_accepts_argumet,args=(val,))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

output: Nothing

whereas:

```
from Multiprocessing import Value,Pool,apply_async
val = Value('i',1)

pool = Pool(processes=2)

pool.apply_async(some_func1_dosen't_accepts_argumet)
pool.apply_async(some_func1_dosen't_accepts_argumet)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Runs fine

tried passing string/int 'tuple' in argument: also runs fine

problem comes for share memory object

```
p1=Process(target=some_func1_accepts_argument,args=(val,))
p2=Process(target=some_func2_accepts_argument,args=(val,))
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Multiprocessing Process runs fine here with val as shared memory object

EXPECTED: two parallel process should come up when using apply_async with a shared memory argument

Answer (score 1):

In order to utilise all the cores, multiprocessing module provides a Pool class. The Pool class represents a pool of worker processes. It has methods which allows tasks to be offloaded to the worker processes in a few different ways.

If you are using the Pool of processes in multiprocessing then for sharing object you have first make it global so that it could be available in every core of machine.Please find the below code:

```
from multiprocessing import Value,Pool, Lock
import time

def some_func1_accepts_argument():
    return value

def some_func2_accepts_argument():
    return value

def init(val):
    global value
    value=val.value

if __name__=='__main__':
    val = Value('i',1)

    pool = Pool(processes=2,initializer=init, initargs=(val,))
    res=pool.apply_async(some_func1_accepts_argument)
    res1=pool.apply_async(some_func2_accepts_argument)
    print(res.get())
    print(res1.get())
```

Above initializer in Pool class would make val available for all processes forked by main process.

Comment: Please upvote the answer, if you think it helps you and others.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to figure out what it is that is making your function crash? The manner in which you call the function looks correct to me so maybe your function is not able to handle the type of the argument you are giving it?

there are probably better ways to do this but maybe change your some_func1_accepts_argument and some_func2_accepts_argument to look like:

```
import traceback

def some_func1_accepts_argument(arg):
    try:
        your original stuff
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        traceback.format_exc()
```

This is similar to: [error_callback in multiprocessing.Pool apply_async in Python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986885/error-callback-in-multiprocessing-pool-apply-async-in-python-2)